# Integrate an MVVM WPF Solution with Caliburn Micro and MEF into an old WPF Applicaion with codbehind and Page Navigation

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Last year I built a WPF application using page navigation and no MVVM.
Recently I was asked to build a new application for the same customer  which I did in WPF MVVM with Caliburn Micro and MEF. Now my customer asks me to integrate the new application into the old one.

My thought was to add a new page to the old application and to integrate the shell of the new application into a `ContentControl` of this page.

My problem now is that the old application is started by an

`<StartupUri="Views\NavWindow.xaml">`

entry in the app.xaml, while the new application is started by a bootstrapper like

`<local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />`

where AppBootstrapper looks like

```
class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel>
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

        CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Count() > 0)
        {
            return exports.First();
        }

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }

}
```

So, as far as I understand, in case of the new app the bootstrapper initializes the whole app, calls the `ShellViewModel` and eventually the `ShellView`.

Because I use the `EventAggregator` in the new app to send messages from one viewmodel to another, I think I can´t just get rid of the bootstrapper and use the view-first model of Caliburn Micro.

So my problem is: can I call the bootstrapper from my old app by myself, and if so, where should I store the instance of it, and how do I tell Caliburn Micro where to put the `ShellView`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CM is so light that in these situations it's actually worth having a peek at the source to see what a particular class is actually doing.

The `Bootstrapper` works because declaring it in the resources file of the application forces an instantiation of it. The constructor calls `Start` on the instance and that sets up the aggregator, IOC, etc.

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4de6f2a26b21#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/Bootstrapper.cs

If you were to load the application into a `ContentControl` in another application, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't kick off CM as the resources for the loaded application would still be processed, instantiating and starting up the `Bootstrapper` etc. Have you tried it in a test project? That might be your first option.

There may be some areas where CMs default implementation of `Bootstrapper` might not be ideal, but on first glance I can't see any glaring issues (not sure what happens to the application events such as `OnStartup` etc when you load a sub-application so you might want to look at that). Worst case you can roll your own `Bootstrapper` for the sub-app and just rebuild with the tweaked functionality.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. I´ll dig into the sourcecode and see what I can find.